# C++ simple code. Need to find repeating adjacent word

Tags: c++

I need to write code that checks whether or not the user inputted the same word twice, and if so, it will output a message stating that they did. So far, I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string previous = "";
    string current = "";

    while (cin>>current); {
        if(current == previous); {
            cout<<"repeated word";
        }
        previous=current;

    }
}
```

It compiles, but it won't output the message whenever the user types in the same word twice.

Comment: remove the `;` after the wille.
also, move the line previous=current at the end of the while loop

Comment: Don't understand why it got a negative vote. This question is clear, has code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you notice, your code contains `;` in places it should not contain.
for example, if you place it after a `while (cin >> current)` then code you wanted to run, won't.

try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string previous = "";
string current = "";

while (cin>>current)
{
      if(current == previous)
      {
              cout<<"repeated word";
      }
      previous=current;

      }
}
```

Comment: Both you and the OP are missing `#include <string>`